# Div starting on bottom of page

Tags: css, html

Hope you can help me out. I'm Dutch, so my English is not very good.

I've got a div and I want it to show at the bottom of the browser, even when you scale the browser window. Same as this website:

http://www.cedricvella.com/#node-3

The content with the white background always starts at the bottom of the browser window, even when it's scaled down. I hope it can be done with pure css!

Answer (score 0):

add the css for the div:

```
.div-class {
   position: fixed;
   left: 0; bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that's not wat I mean. It's hard to explain. I don't want it to be fixed. I want, if someone enters my website that they will see a full size image with my logo (i already have this part). But when they scroll, i want my website to start showing my content. Problem with a standard position is when someone scales his browser vertically, you have to scroll much further before reaching the content! I want the content always beginning at the bottom of my page, so it shows up instantly when someone scrolls down, even with a smaller browser window... So hard to explain what i mean, haha!

Comment: I think I understand :) But you can't do this only with CSS, I think. But with jquery, it's easy to do, just add the div with your image a height of the browser window height.
You can use this https://github.com/louisremi/jquery-smartresize plugin if you want to trigger some action on browser resize, or the jquery .resize() function.
And place the rest of the content below your starting div

Answer (score 0):

Check [this demo in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RC2xN/)

CSS

```
body{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
.footer{
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    text-align:center;
    background:#999;
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="footer">this is fixed area with align bottom</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, that's not wat I mean. It's hard to explain. I don't want it to be fixed. I want, if someone enters my website that they will see a full size image with my logo (i already have this part). But when they scroll, i want my website to start showing my content. Problem with a standard position is when someone scales his browser vertically, you have to scroll much further before reaching the content! I want the content always beginning at the bottom of my page, so it shows up instantly when someone scrolls down, even with a smaller browser window... So hard to explain what i mean, haha!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about a footer, you should take a look at [Ryan Fait's method](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/).

It uses a wrapper with a `.push` element to keep the footer element at the bottom.

Like so:

```
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -142px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}
.footer, .push {
    height: 142px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
}
```